# Can't cast generic

Tags: java, generics

I understand why I can't cast one class that generelized with A, to same class that generelized with B (if B extends A). It's explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html). But I have no clue why this code doesn't work.

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D<? extends B> d = new D<>();
        d.foo(new B()); // compilation error
        d.foo(new C()); // compilation error
    }
}

class B {

}

class C extends B {

}

class D<T> {
  void foo(T t) {

  }
}
```

I would like to have the reference to official docs where this principle is explained.

Comment: Oops...........

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Hmm, the "duplicated" question and its answers do not answer this question. Let alone there is no reference to the docs about this...